# How do I write n ∈ all of the known number sets

Tags: recreational-mathematics

If I want to say that n ∈ all of the known number sets do I have to write n ∈ 
$\mathbb{N} , \mathbb{Z} , \mathbb{Q} , \mathbb{R} , \mathbb{C}$ or should I just leave it blank?

Comment: Someone please help :)

Comment: Since quaternions exists, $\mathbb C$ is not enough.

Comment: Define "all the known number sets".

Comment: @Peter Do not forget octonions and sedenions

Comment: The expression "all of the known number sets" is unlucky because for every element $n$ , we can chose a number set NOT containing $n$. We could for example choose the negative numbers or the irrational numbers or ...

Comment: I am working on a math theorem and I just want to say that they can choose any number n and it will still work in my formulas.

Comment: @OpenHax I sincerely doubt you can plug in *any* number. What about a sedenion? A 2-adic? A surreal? You should state the theorem you are trying to prove precisely, and not shoot for too great (and, almost certainly, false) generality.

Comment: Well I already tested it with N,Z,Q,R,C . I formulated wrongly when I said any number. But still, should I write that n ∈ N,Z,Q,R,C or should I leave it blank ?

Comment: @OpenHax Do you mean a set that big that it contains every number we know, including p-adics,quaternions and so on ?

Comment: No. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

If $n\in \mathbb{N}$, it is also in all the other sets you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

If $n\in \Bbb{N}$, it follows that $n$ belongs to all of the other sets you listed  since $\Bbb{N}$ is a subset of all of them.

$$\Bbb{N}\subseteq\Bbb{Z}\subseteq\Bbb{Q}\subseteq\Bbb{R}\subseteq\Bbb{C}$$

Answer (score 1):

1) $n ∈ H$

2) $for all H ∈ \{\mathbb{N} , \mathbb{Z} , \mathbb{Q} , \mathbb{R} , \mathbb{C} \}$

observe that in step 2, I didn't use the inclusion, but H is indeed an element of this "weird" set of sets. example:

Using step 2, since H belongs to this set of sets, then it must be for example that $H=\mathbb{Q}$.

Then by step 1 $n ∈ \mathbb{Q}$

Answer (score 0):

I believe $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a number set as well, and smaller than $\mathbb{N}$.

And the set of imaginary numbers $\mathbb{I}$ has nothing in common with $\mathbb{N}$.